# ActiveMQ processing message multiple times

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

I would like to set up redelivery policy in ActiveMQ.
I have set up  retry attempts to 3 times and after that message should be sent to Dead Letter queue. However I have noticed that while 3 attempts of processing message (when exception occurs) is processed **multiple** times. Why?

1. First time of processing - message is processed 13 (1 regular and 12 reprocessing one by one) times (exception occurs every time so message is sent back to queue eventually - at the end of 13th time)
2. Second processing - message is processed 5 times
3. Third time - message is reprocessed 4 times

Why this extra reprocessing? I thought that when message is sent back to queue then my listener should get this message and again try to process this message only once. Which parameter is responsible for this reprocessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to add `jms.redeliveryPolicy.maximumRedeliveries=0` to the connection URI. By default the ActiveMQ client retries on the client side. That is all very well, but if you have configured the broker to handle retries you normally don't want the client to do it as well. Just add the option. See http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html for the option itself.

Comment: You are right! Instead of setting up URI parameters I have made changes in Java code: ActiveMQConnectionFactory gets RedeliveryPolicy object. We can set this parameter directly on this object. I set up to 0 and all the other settings have been taken from my XML ActiveMQ settings! Thanks a lot!